# Saving html for offline usage (Jsoup, CommonsIO)

Tags: android, html, save, jsoup, apache-commons-io

I want to save an html file for offline usage and therefore use Jsoup and CommonsIO. (the webview cache is no option for me)

On the first launch, the html-file should be (displayed in a webview) and downloaded and stored on the device's internal storage (or somewhere else). If the Activity is launched again the data should be received from the stored html-file.

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

View myView;
WebView myWebView;
Document doc;
String str;

@JavascriptInterface
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myWebView = myView.findViewById(R.id.webview2);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("first", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean firstlauch = prefs.getBoolean("first", true);

    if (firstlauch){

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "online", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        prefs.edit().putBoolean("first", false).apply();

        new doit().execute();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "offline", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        File getfile = new File("wikihome.html");

        try {
            str = FileUtils.readFileToString(getfile, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myWebView.loadData(str, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
    }

    return myView;
}
```

An AsyncTask downloads and saves the html-file.

```
public class doit extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Connection.Response html = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page").execute();
            doc = html.parse();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        try {
        File file = new File("wikihome.html");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, doc.outerHtml(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when the Activity is launched the second time, all I get is a white screen.

(Displaying the content when it's directly parsed from Jsoup works, so I guess the problem is somewhere in the process of saving and retrieving the file.)

Note: is this a good workaround, or do you recommend me a different way to do this?

Comment: You download the file. Once you have it on disk, can you open it manually in the Web browser?

Comment: well I save it to the internal storage, without root acces I can't get the file

Comment: Sorry for my response a bit doubtful, but if you are saying that without root acces I can't get the file, maybe this is the same reason why it cannot be displayed from the application? Unless you are running the application with root access, very dangerous.

Comment: from the android developer page: (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#InternalVsExternalStorage)

Internal storage: (is) always available. Files saved here are accessible by only your app.

Comment: Maybe I understood you wrong, I can't access the file, but the app should be able to do so

Comment: Debug your app - add a breakpoint at `onPostExecute` and check the value of `doc.outerHtml()`. Add another breakpoint after reading the data from the file. See if both results match.

Comment: I think when I read the data, I get
**java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin**